# Expand a netCDF Variable into an additional Dimension or multiple Variables

Tags: r, raster, netcdf

I am working with a very large netCDF file in three dimensions (lat/lon/time). The resolution is 300 meters and the time variable has 25 steps, which leads to 64800x129600x25 cells.

The one variable contained in the file is an integer (ranging from -36 to 120) but represents an underlying factor, which is the problem.
It is a land cover data set, so for example: -20 means the cell is of the land type ***Forest*** or 10 means the cell is covered by ***water***.

I want to reshape the netCDF file such that there is an additional dimension which represents every factor level of the original variable. And the variable would then be just a 1 or 0 per cell indicating the presence of every factor level at a certain lat/lon/time.
The dimensions would then be lat/lon/time/*land type*.

[Here](http://schubert.atmos.colostate.edu/%7Ecslocum/code/air.sig995.2012.nc) is an example data set, that does not concern land type but is small enough that it can be used for testing. And here is some code to read it in:

```
library(ncdf4)
# Download the data
download.file("http://schubert.atmos.colostate.edu/~cslocum/code/air.sig995.2012.nc", 
          mode="wb", destfile = "test.nc")
test.ncdf <- nc_open("test.nc", write=TRUE)
# See the lon,lat,time dimensions
print(test.ncdf)
tmp.array <- ncvar_get(test.ncdf, varid="air")
```

I'm not sure if the `raster` package is better more suited for this task. For very small netCDF-files I have managed the intended result to some extent, by extracting the data and then stacking it as a data.frame.

Any help or pointing in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to have a set of fields for each **type** that are 1 or 0 as a function of lat/long/time.  e.g. if you are looking a forest you want an array which is 1 when the factor=20 and 0 otherwise.

I know you want to do this in a 4 dimensional array, for that you will need to use R I expect as you tagged the question.  But if you don't mind to have a series of 3D arrays for types, a quick and easy way to do this is to use CDO to process the integer array

```
cdo eqc,-20 air.sig995.2012.nc test.nc
```

The issue with this is that the output variable still has the same name 
(you don't say what it is called, so I refer to it as *sfctype*), and so you would need to change the meta data with nco.

Therefore a better way would be to use **expr** in cdo.

```
cdo expr,"forest=sfctype==-20" air.sig995.2012.nc forest.nc
```

This makes a new variable called *forest* which is 1 or 0.
You could now process all the types you want, and then merge them into one file:

```
 cdo expr,"forest=(sfctype==-20)" air.sig995.2012.nc type_forest.nc
 cdo expr,"forest=(sfctype==10)" air.sig995.2012.nc type_water.nc
 ...etc...
 cdo merge type_*.nc combined_file.nc
```

(I don't think you need the curly brackets, but it is a clearer syntax)

...*almost* what you wanted in a few lines, but not quite...  I am not sure how to "stack" these new variables into a 4D array if you *really* need that, but perhaps nco can do it.